# What is the difference between Software Components and Software Devices in Window's Device Manager?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, device-manager

What is the difference between Software Components and Software Devices in Window's Device Manager?

The answers that I could find online weren't satisfactory. For Software Devices, I understand that they could include devices that are emulated in software, partial functions of hardware that are done in software or virtual devices. For software components, [the only article that I could find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-a-component-inf-file) mentions that they are additional software modules that can provide enhanced features features.

Comment: I guess I do not understand. I have hardware drivers and then added functionally under Software Components that are related to hardware and Software Devices that are Printers and a couple of drivers related to hardware. Nothing seems out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite a specific answer, but leaving it here nonetheless as it may shorten some research for someone.

These device manager categories have the following PnP classes:

- `SoftwareComponent` (GUID: `5c4c3332-344d-483c-8739-259e934c9cc8`)
- `SoftwareDevice` (GUID: `62f9c741-b25a-46ce-b54c-9bccce08b6f2`)

---

`SoftwareComponent` is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/system-defined-device-setup-classes-available-to-vendors) as:

> (Windows 10 version 1703 and later versions of Windows) This class includes virtual child device to encapsulate software components. For more details, see [Adding Software Components with an INF file](https://Adding%20Software%20Components%20with%20an%20INF%20file.).

That link includes some more information:

> A software component is a separate, standalone driver package that can install one or more software modules. The installed software enhances the value of the device, but is not necessary for basic device functionality and does not require an associated function driver service.

---

Not much can be found about `SoftwareDevice`.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/system-defined-device-setup-classes-reserved-for-system-use) lists it with no description as "reserved for system use". It seems that Windows doesn't want vendors to use this class, yet I see various vendor-related drivers there, such as `HP DeskJet 2700 series`.